# List Index out of range error in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to solve the [max path sum problem](https://projecteuler.net/problem=18) from project euler.

**CODE:**

```
def main():
        data = [map(int,row.split()) for row in open("Triangle.txt")]
        print data
        for i in range(len(data)-2,-1,-1):
           for j in range(i+1):
                data[i][j] += max([data[i+1][j],data[i+1][j+1]]) #list out of range error
        print (data[0][0])

if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

The data value has 16 internal lists as follows:

```
[[75], [95, 64], [17, 47, 82], [18, 35, 87, 10], [20, 4, 82, 47, 65], [19, 1, 23, 75, 3, 34], [88, 2, 77, 73, 7, 63, 67], [99, 65, 4, 28, 6, 16, 70, 92], [41, 41, 26, 56, 83, 40, 80, 70, 33], [41, 48, 72, 33, 47, 32, 37, 16, 94, 29], [53, 71, 44, 65, 25, 43, 91, 52, 97, 51, 14], [70, 11, 33, 28, 77, 73, 17, 78, 39, 68, 17, 57], [91, 71, 52, 38, 17, 14, 91, 43, 58, 50, 27, 29, 48], [63, 66, 4, 68, 89, 53, 67, 30, 73, 16, 69, 87, 40, 31], [4, 62, 98, 27, 23, 9, 70, 98, 73, 93, 38, 53, 60, 4, 23], []]
```

And I am getting `list index out of range` error in the line:

```
data[i][j] += max([data[i+1][j],data[i+1][j+1]])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

How can i get rid of this error?
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the last item in `data`. It's an empty list. Try removing it and executing the script, as follows:

```
In [392]: data[-1]
Out[392]: []

In [393]: data = data[:-1]

In [394]: for i in range(len(data)-2,-1,-1):
   .....:     for j in range(i+1):
   .....:         data[i][j] += max([data[i+1][j],data[i+1][j+1]]) #list out of range error
   .....: print (data[0][0])
   .....: 
1074
```

In order to eliminate the error altogether, without the need to manually alter the contents of `data`, you can read it correctly at the first place, as follows:

```
data = [map(int,row.split()) for row in open("Triangle.txt") if row.strip()]
```